# How to resolve "Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings"?

Tags: knockout.js, single-page-application

In my application I'm binding data from an API to a `ul` successfully. However, I'm unable to have KO call the function bound to the click event of an `a` tag. I got below error:

> Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
>   Message: ReferenceError: loadContact is not defined;
>   Bindings value: click: loadContact,attr: { title: 1}

View code:

```html
<ul data-role="listview" id="ListSss" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
     <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
          Criteria Selected
      </li>
      <!-- ko foreach: Contacts  -->
      <li data-theme="c"> 
          <a href="#" data-transition="slide" data-bind="click: loadsss,attr: { title: sss }">
              <span data-bind="text: FName + ' ' + LName + ' (' + Classifiy +':'+ Position+ ')'" ></span>
          </a>
      </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

JS code:

```
  self.loadsss = function () {
       alert("hi");
    }
```

Because of href link present in foreach thats why I'm unable to fire click event of href?  Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Can you add the viewmodel ?

Comment: You're probably making the mistake in a bit of code that you haven't posted. The code you posted (when extended to make an [sscce](http://sscce.org)) will [work just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/UX6cF/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that, `loadContact` function is used inside `for-loop`, but `loadContact` function is a part of `viewModel`, not a part of single contact.
Use `$parent.loadContact` instead.

```
  <a href="#" data-transition="slide" data-bind="click: $parent.loadContact,attr: { title: ContactID }">
      <span data-bind="text: FirstName + ' ' + LastName + ' (' + Classification +':'+ Position+ ')'" ></span>
  </a>
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rVfxn/)